# SQL Query, getting results from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, clients and clients_role.

when i enter in a role, i need it to check the clients_role table to see if there are any entries, if there are, get the user_id from the clients_role then match the user_id to the id in the clients table.

Does this make sense?

if anyone could help, it would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, here it is:

SELECT id FROM clients WHERE id IN (SELECT user_id FROM clients_role WHERE role = "YOURROLE")

Comment: yes, SELECT * FROM clients. And I think that YOURROLE is between single quotes, like 'YOURROLE'

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
select c.* 
from clients_role r 
inner join clients c
on c.user_id = r.user_id
where r.role = blah
```

this returns all the clients that have a user_id in the clients_roles tables.

Comment: This didnt work, Im getting Unknown column '_wfa' in 'where clause'